# Can't update computer policy from samba DC

Tags: group-policy, samba, samba4

I'm trying to push out a CA cert to my clients, but their group policy isn't updating. When I try `gpupdate /force`, I get:

```
Computer policy could not be updated successfully. The following errors were encountered:

The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted to read the file
\\[domain]\sysvol\[domain]\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini
from a domain controller and was not successful. Group Policy settings
may not be applied until this event is resolved. This issue may be transient and
could be caused by one or more of the following:
a) Name Resolution/Network Connectivity to the current domain controller.
b) File Replication Service Latency (a file created on another domain controller
has not replicated to the current domain controller).
c) The Distributed File System (DFS) client has been disabled.
User Policy update has completed successfully.

To diagnose the failure, review the event log or run GPRESULT /H GPReport.html
from the command line to access information about Group Policy results.
```

I can access `\\[domain]\sysvol\[domain]\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini` in file explorer without a problem.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew it was a permissions error of some sort. Eventually I found that just running the command `samba-tool ntacl sysvolreset` as root on the DC fixed it.